# Is it possible to avoid setting interrupt number in devicetree?

Tags: linux-device-driver

In another words, if didn't set line "`interrupts = <x y z>`" in device's devicetree entry (and my specific interrupt number doesn't mentioned elsewhere in the dts file):

1. Would kernel receive interrupt and increment intr line in /proc/stat?
2. Would a driver execute interrupt handler (if it was registered earlier with hardcoded correct interrupt number via request_irq call)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, if you register irq handler with proper line number in , you will receive the interrupt fine, doesn't matter if it is passed from dts or you have hard coded in driver itself.